# Is it possible to bring Cicero back to life?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I killed Cicero and now I feel guilty. I'm an assassin, yes, but he was a dark brother after  all. I hear he's also good at sneaking and I like having followers with me, but other followers aren't as good at sneaking and get me detected. Now his corpse lies in the Dawnstar Sanctuary and I have to stare at him. It's driving me crazy.

Is there a way to bring him back permanently and not as a zombie for 60 sec? Are there any in-game means? Or a console command, perhaps?

Comment: Just an FYI, I have read that he is actually one of the more amusing NPCs to bring back as a permanent undead with high level conjuration.

Comment: but he wont stay up forever, or will he?

Comment: There is the Master level summon of a Dead Thrall which works only on Humans, they last permanently (well they can be killed or what not but they dont have an existance timer, none of the Thrall level spells do). On a foot note, this is how you can get 4-5 followers by having the perks to get 2 undead and raise 2 conjurers as thralls who will raise their own pets as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facing the same situation, I spent a morning studying how the console command actually works. After being inspired by UESPWiki's illustration on [the difference between RefID and BaseID](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs), I used the following steps of command, and it worked for me, as I've finished the quest "Hail Sithis!" of Dark Brotherhood.
(ps. I typed these commands in Dawnstar Sanctuary, but I guess it doesn't matter.)

```
prid 0009BCB0
enable
moveto player
```

Then, Cicero appeared, and I could talk to him to trigger the follower conversation.

Answer (score 3):

Open the console, click on his corpse and type in "resurrect".
The character will still be recognized as dead regarding quests etc.

More information on the command over at [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console).

In addition, if you get your conjuration up to 90+, there is a perk which allows for an infinite duration of conjured/resurrected followers.. He would still be your undead follower.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any drawback that he will be regarded as dead?

Comment: Any idea if he will remain hostile, since he died in a battle with me?

Comment: @Evgeni Thralls will not be hostile to you, as they are basically zombis